# Find a strings location in a list - Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have a series of lists in a dictionary (for example):

```
{'Name': ['Thomas', 'Steven', 'Pauly D'], 'Age': [30, 50, 29]}
```

and I want to find the strings position so I can then get the same position from the other list.

So e.g.

```
if x = 'Thomas' #is in position 2:
    y = dictionary['Age'][2]
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the best way to implement this? How are you certain that these lists are in the same order? Also, how is 'Thomas' in position 2? That's not clear.

Comment: I mean that if Thomas is in position two. The commented area is where there is the code I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = dictionary['Name'].index('Thomas')
y = dictionary['Age'][i]
```

However, `index` performs a linear search, which could be slow for a large list.  In other cases similar to this, I've used a pattern like this:

```
Person = collections.namedtuple('Person', ['Name', 'Age'])
dictionary = {'Thomas': Person('Thomas', 30), 'Steven': Person('Steven', 50), 'Pauly D': Person('Pauly D', 29)}
```

You could do the same thing with a dict if you needed the records to be different length.  Either way, storing it like this will help accessing records be faster.

Answer (score 5):

Store it in the proper structure in the first place.

```
D = dict(zip(dictionary['Name'], dictionary['Age']))
print D['Thomas']
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [.index()](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

```
d = {'Name': ['Thomas', 'Steven', 'Pauly D'], 'Age': [30, 50, 29]}
position = d['Name'].index('Steven')
age = d['Age'][position]
```

or `age = d['Age'][d['Name'].index('Steven')]` more densely.

Answer (score 0):

```
infoDict = {
    'Name': ['Thomas', 'Steven', 'Pauly D'],
   'Age':   [30, 50, 29]
}

def getAge(name, d):
    offs = d['Name'].index(name)
    return d['Age'][offs]

getAge('Thomas', infoDict)
```